# Nginx Server stopped working after installing ngx-pagespeed mod

Tags: nginx, mod-pagespeed

I had NGINX running fine on my local machine and tried to install the Google Page Speed module by first [uninstalling nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-install-ngx_pagespeed-module-in-ubuntu-14-04-where-nginx-server-is-already-installed) and following the re-installing from source [as Google suggests](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source).

Now NGINX won't start, and I can't access any of the sites I have set up locally for development.  There is nothing in my error logs, yet I can see I have the /etc/nginx/ directory with all the configuration files I had before.

Any idea how I can get things working again?

I tried re-installing but still no joy :(

Answer (score 0):

Got it working I had to replace the /etc/nginx directory with a backup I took of it before I tried anything with ngx-pagespeed.  Now it works as before but pity ngx-pagespeed did not work.